# Update list items based on current month in C#

Tags: c#

I have a collections of records in list. Now I have a data table with few records. My list sample is here:

```csh
List<TimeControlGrid> EmpList = new List<TimeControlGrid>();
EmpList = (from DataRow dr in Oracleresult.Rows
            select new TimeControlGrid()
            {
                EmpNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EMPNUMBER"]),
                EmpName = dr["EMPNAME"].ToString(),
                Dept = dr["DEPT"].ToString(),
                ProjectName = dr["PROJECTNAME"].ToString(),
                ChargeDesc = dr["CHARGEDESC"].ToString(),
                ProjectCode= dr["PROJECTCODE"].ToString(),
                CostCenter= dr["COSTCENTER"].ToString(),
                Jan = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jan"]),
                Feb = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Feb"]),
                Mar = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mar"]),
                Apr = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Apr"]),
                May = Convert.ToInt32(dr["May"]),
                Jun = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jun"]),
                Jul = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jul"]),
                Aug = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Aug"]),
                Sep = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sep"]),
                Oct = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Oct"]),
                Nov = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Nov"]),
                Dec = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Dec"]) )
            }).ToList();
```

I have a datatable with same columns but it has few value changes in months columns, so here is my requirement:

First I need to get current month. If current month is **Jan** then I need to update all months values for that record in list with data table values.

Suppose if current month value is **Dec** then I need to update only **Dec** month value in list with data table values. Below is the code sample where I need to apply my changes. In below code I am just checking with month. Current month is **Dec**. So, I just need to update **Dec** value only. Like this way suppose if current month is **Nov** then I need to update **Nov** and **Dec** values in emplist.

```csh
foreach(DataRow dr in SQLresult.Rows)
{
    var obj = EmpList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ProjectName== dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ChargeDesc == dr["ChargeDesc"].ToString() && x.CostCenter == dr["CostCenter"].ToString());
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() == "12")
        {
            obj.Dec = dr["Dec"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on why you have 12 months as columns in the DB table. Better schema could be to have 2 tables - 'Employee' table with all columns excluding Jan, Feb.. 'MonthlyValues' table with columns (empid, monthid, value).

Anyway with the current schema, you can utilize the [datarow.item property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0). Pseudo code like what follows -

```
    int currMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    for (int monthIndex = currMonth; monthIndex <= 12; monthIndex++)
        obj.item[monthIndex] = dr.item[monthIndex]
```